# Client side not working in method accessible by client and server in Meteor

Tags: meteor

I'm trying to test the latency compensation by adding a delay in the server side code of a method that inserts a document in a collection. The idea is that when the method is running "mirrored" in the client, the title of the post inserted will have "*(client)*" concatenated to it, and then when the method runs in the server, it will have "*(server)*" concatenated to its title. Since I set a delay of 5 seconds for the server, I should see the post title changing proving how the latency compensation works.

The file I have implementing this method is under */lib/collections* folder, so it should be accessible by both the server and client, however it doesn't work, I never see the "*(client)*" text in the titles, only "*(server)*" and the post doesn't show up until the 5 seconds have passed, so it seems that the client side code is not working, only the server one.

This is the source of the file (*/lib/collections/post.js*) where the method is defined:

```
Posts=new Mongo.Collection('posts');

Meteor.methods({
    postAdd:function(postAttributes){

        check(Meteor.userId(),String);
        check(postAttributes,{
            title:String,
            url:String
        });

        if(Meteor.isServer){
            postAttributes.title+=' (server)';
            Meteor._sleepForMs(5000);
        }else{
            postAttributes.title+=' (client)';
        }

        var posWithTheSameLink=Posts.findOne({url:postAttributes.url});
        if(posWithTheSameLink){
            return {
                postExists:true,
                _id:posWithTheSameLink._id
            }
        }

        var user=Meteor.user();
        var post=_.extend(postAttributes,{
            userId:user._id,
            author:user.username,
            submitted:new Date()
        });
        var postId=Posts.insert(post);
        return {
            _id:postId
        };
    }
});
```

And this is the source of the file (*/client/templates/postAdd.js*) where the event is triggered:

```
Template.postAdd.events({
    'submit form':function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var post={
            url:$(e.target).find('[name=url]').val(),
            title:$(e.target).find('[name=title]').val(),
            user_id:Meteor.userId
        };
        Meteor.call('postAdd',post,function(error,result){
            if(error) return alert(error.reason);
            if(result.postExists) alert('This link has been already posted.');
            //Router.go('postPage',{_id:result._id});
        });
        Router.go('postsList');
    }
});
```

If I add the following in the *post.js* file right after the `Posts=new Mongo.Collection('posts');` :

```
if(Meteor.isClient){ alert('This is the client!'); }
```

I do see the message popping up, so the post.js file is definetely accessible by the client.

It seems that any client code inside the method definition won't work.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: On a side note, I have written a package to prevent this type of hackery. It is called [`lag-console`](https://atmospherejs.com/alon/lag-console) and allows you to delay publications and method calls.

Answer (score 0):

Being a beginner at Meteor, I was wondering the same thing.

I found some info regarding Method Life-Cycle, which you might find useful, [here](http://guide.meteor.com/methods.html#call-lifecycle).

Also I tried running a simplified version of your code:

```
DB = new Mongo.Collection('db');

Meteor.methods({
  'test': function(data) {
    if (Meteor.isServer) {
        data.title += ' (server)';
        Meteor._sleepForMs(50000); // here I increased the delay just to be sure
    } else {
        data.title += ' (client)';
    }

    DB.insert(data);
    if (this.isSimulation) { // logged the output before server response came
        console.log(DB.find().fetch());
    }
    if (Meteor.isServer) {
        console.log(DB.find().fetch());
    }
  }
});
```

This gave me the expected output. I got the `(client)` output from the browser, data had been inserted into the client-side DB but not the server-side DB. Once, server-side DB got new data, my client-side document automatically changed to `(server)`.